# Inno Setup installer cannot run application just installed by child installer (Unable to run Node. Create process failed)

Tags: node.js, inno-setup, pascalscript

I have written script to install Node.js, run shell script and Windows service using Inno Setup. I have created a setup. When I install my setup Node.js gets successfully installed.

```
[Run]    
Filename: "msiexec.exe"; Parameters: "/i ""{app}\nodejs\node-v8.11.1-x64.msi""";
```

Shell scripts runs successfully.

```pascal
[Code]
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  ErrorCode: Integer;
  ReturnCode: Boolean;
begin
  ExtractTemporaryFile('Add-AppDevPackage.ps1');
  ReturnCode :=
    ShellExec('open', '"PowerShell"',
    ExpandConstant(' -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden  -File "{app}\setup\Add-AppDevPackage.ps1"'),
    '', SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ErrorCode);

    if (ReturnCode = False) then
        MsgBox('Message about problem. Error code: ' + IntToStr(ErrorCode) + ' ' + SysErrorMessage(ErrorCode),
          mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```

But when I try to run Windows service which is a .js file (`installservice.js`), I get an error like

> Unable to run node. Create Process failed code2.

Code used to run the node:

```
[Run]
Filename: "node"; Parameters: "installservice.js"; WorkingDir: "{app}\nodepath"; \
    Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent runascurrentuser; AfterInstall: MsbShow;
```

And I also found that **if the Node JS is already installed** in the machine then the **Windows service installs and runs perfectly**. I don't know where the error is. I even tried to run the Windows service post install but still the problem persist. Can you guide me in this process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `[Run]` entry relies on the `node` to be in `PATH`.

That won't be the case, if you installed Note.js just now, as the change in `PATH` by the Node.js installer won't be reflected in already running processes (particularly your Inno Setup installer).

For details, see:
[Environment variable not recognized [not available] for [Run] programs in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21708140/850848)

---

Instead, specify an absolute path to the `node` in [`Filename` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection&anchor=Filename). Something like:

```
[Run]
Filename: "{pf}\Node.js\node"; ...
```

or set a working directory using [`WorkingDir` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection&anchor=WorkingDir):

```
[Run]
Filename: "node"; WorkingDir: "{pf}\Node.js"
```